# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, toggle

I am developing a website in React, and I have a card component. I want to pass a function as a prop to this component, but something doesn't work properly and I don't know.

```
 render() {
return (
  <div className="Subject-div">
    <div id="subjects">
      <Flippy
        flipOnHover={false} 
        flipOnClick={false} 
        flipDirection="horizontal" 
        ref={(r) => (this.flippy = r)} 
        style={{ width: "inherit", height: "inherit" }}
      >

        <FrontSide id="subject-card-front-side">
          <img
            id="subject-card-front-image"
            src={this.props.image}
            alt={this.props.alt}
          />

          <div id="subject-card-front-div">

            <Button
              variant="contained"
              id="subject-card-front-button"
              onClick={this.props.function}
            >
              {this.props.title}
            </Button>

          </div>

        </FrontSide>

        <BackSide id="subject-card-back-side">
          {" "}
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            id="subject-card-back-button-back"
            }}
          >

            Inapoi

          </Button>
         
        </BackSide>
      </Flippy>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

And I have the other component

```
 export class ListaMaterii extends React.Component {  render() {
return (
  <div id="lista-materii">
    <SubjectCard
      title="Matematica"
      image={mate}
      alt="Matematica"
      indisponibil="Lectii indisponibile"
      function={() => {
        this.flippy.toggle();
      }}
    />
```

And when I click the button, it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined"
What can I do in this case?

Comment: this happens because `flippy` is `undefined`. now, you may need to include the code where you are defining `flippy` to find the issue, since the code you paste doesn't have it.

Comment: Can you explain me in more detail? How can I do it?

Comment: you have `ListaMaterii` class, but in your class you don't define `flippy` anywhere. if it's passed through props than it should be `this.props.flippy.toggle();`

Comment: Can you share the code for SubjectCard component